# Is there a limit to the amount of caps you can have?

Tags: fallout-shelter

[image: Maximum Caps is one million? Or bug?]

My cap amount is stuck at the amount on the screen shot. Is this a bug, or have I hit a hard limit?

Comment: Does it stay like that when you spend any as well?

Comment: I recommend spending those caps on demolishing all of those 1 space and many of the 2 space rooms and turning them into 3 space rooms. I'd also demolish all the first tier production rooms and replacing them with their second tier replacements, except fewer of them. You should be able to make your vault smaller, more efficient and easier to manage.

Answer (score 13):

Congrats on being a super rich vault!

**Vaults can hold a maximum of 999,999 caps.** Any more you collect from production rooms, level ups, exploring the wasteland, selling items, or anything other than lunchboxes will not increase your caps beyond 999,999.

As with all other lunchbox related things, **lunchboxes ignore the cap on caps**. Any cap cards you pull from a lunchbox (x100, x500, etc) will add their full amount of caps to the total, even if it puts you over 999,999.

You will accumulate caps normally again once you spend enough caps for your total to drop below 999,999.